# Visual Studio Code-Cannot open source file "iostream"

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-code

I just want to try c++ coding with Visual Studio code. I have installed vscode 1.18.1 to my laptop (Win10-64).

I got errors by typing following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world!" <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Should happen no Error. C:\Users\Harri\OneDrive\Tiedostot\Demo2.vscode\c_cpp_properties.json -content:

"path": [
                    "/usr/include",
                    "/usr/local/include",
                    "${workspaceRoot}"
                ],

Problems/Errors for row 1:

" #include errors detected. Please update your includePath. IntelliSense features for this translation unit (C:\Users\Harri\OneDrive\Tiedostot\Demo2\Calc.cpp) will be provided by the Tag Parser. "

" cannot open source file "iostream" "

Comment: An Extension Ms-C/C++ (ms-vscode.cpptools) is installed

Comment: Could somone much more wiser help me with the Windows PATH problems to the vscode Extensions? The current path only define: 
CMD>>PATH= ...;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin

Extensions are located on the C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions -folder, I think. 

Windows search: %USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions  Does not found the correct path.

Comment: You didn't describe what compiler you actually. The file `iostream` should be installed by the compiler. What is the actual path of that include file, i.e. what path must be added to the `dir` command in the Windows command prompt to list the file with `dir`?

Answer (score 0):

#### The main problem is cygwin paths

You have cygwin paths like `/usr/include` in your `c_cpp_properties.json` file.  That is a problem because VSCode does not understand cygwin paths.  At a cygwin shell you can run:

```
  $ cygpath -w /usr/include
  D:\cygwin64\usr\include
```

to get the equivalent Windows path.  Put that into `c_cpp_properties.json` instead.  Remember that you have to double the backslashes when you copy this into a JSON string.

#### Other suggestions

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56457210/2659307) describes how to set up VSCode with cygwin gcc.  I haven't tried those instructions but they look reasonable.

Beyond that, I highly recommend going through the [Get Started with C++](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) tutorial on the VSCode site.  It might directly answer your question, but even if it doesn't, having a working setup to compare to is valuable.

Also, look at the C/C++ diagnostics: View → Command Palette... → C/C++: Log Diagnostics.  This will show things like which compiler VSCode is trying to emulate and what it thinks the #include paths are.

Finally, to get lots of useful information directly from your compiler to compare with what VSCode thinks, if you are using gcc, run at a cygwin or bash prompt:

```
  $ touch empty.c
  $ gcc -v -E -dD empty.c > compiler-info.txt
```

That will write to `compiler-info.txt` all the predefined macros, #include search paths, default target, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but it was easily solved by setting the "Compiler path" in the C/C++ configurations. VS Code then found the library directly and compiled the project.

[image: Screenshot from settings screen in VS Code]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541, https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson