# Setting up VS Code for C using Cygwin64 Compiler and Debugger on Windows

Tags: c, cygwin, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

Would like to set up VS Code to work with Cygwin/Cygwin64.
Already have these set up:

1. Installed Cygwin64 on windows
2. Installed gcc (Compiler) and gdb (Debugger) packages from Cygwin installer
3. GCC and GDB are **NOT** in windows path.
4. Installed Visual Studio Code

Posting this because it took me a couple of days from multiple different sources to set this up.
This is specifically for Windows with Cygwin/Cygwin64 installed.

DISCLAIMER: I've only tested this for building single files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instructions here are for setting up on VS Code

1. Install the extension C/C++ on VS Code

```
Name: C/C++
Id: ms-vscode.cpptools
Description: C/C++ IntelliSense, debugging, and code browsing.
Version: 0.23.1
Publisher: Microsoft
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools
```

2. If you have a workspace already, skip this step.

   Create a folder and add this folder into VS Code. Then save workspace.
3. Set up `launch.json`

   Go to "Debug > Open Configurations", this should open the launch.json file. Below is my configuration. If you're testing this and unsure of what you're doing, I suggest you save your original content somewhere before replacing things.

   *Note: `"preLaunchTask": "gcc.exe build active file"` runs the task labelled "gcc.exe build active file".*

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gcc.exe build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "PATH",
                    "value": "%PATH%;z:\\cygwin64\\bin"
                }
            ],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "logging": { "engineLogging": true }, //optional
            "preLaunchTask": "gcc.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

4. Set up `task.json`

   Go to "Terminal > Configure Tasks..." and select "gcc.exe build active file"

   The various "-W" flags in "args" are meant to make the compiler more strict. You can remove them if you'd like.

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "-Werror", // Optional
                "-Wall", // Optional
                "-Wextra", // Optional
                "-ansi", // Optional
                "-pedantic", // Optional
                "${file}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\cygwin64\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

5. Build and Debug Active File

   Go to the C file you want to build, press Ctrl+Shift+P for "Command Palette > C/C++ Build and Debug Active File > gcc.exe build active file" or if you only want to build then go to "Terminal > Run Build Task".

Comment: launch.js and task.js must be in the .vscode folder which is in the folder where the .cpp file is stored

Answer (score -3):

Cygwin64 is inefficient because it is using a medium memory model. This makes it use 64 bit absolute addresses instead of 32 bit relative addresses for static data.

I will recommend to use the Clang plugin for Visual Studio instead, unless you have a specific reason to use Cygwin64. See https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/clang-llvm-support-in-visual-studio/

You also get rid of the cygwin DLL when using the Clang plugin.

Comment: Is this wrt VSCode similar to the original question, or Visual Studio?

Comment: I think clang works fine with both Visual Studio and VSCode.

Comment: The original question was about Cygwin integration, so answers of the form "don't use Cygwin" seem off-topic.