# Setting up VS Code for C using Cygwin64 Compiler and Debugger on Windows (ERROR: Unable to start debugging)

Tags: c, debugging, cygwin, visual-studio-code

I am trying to set up VSCODE to **debug** a C program on Windows using Cygwin64.

I used the config suggested by @stephw ( [Setting up VS Code for C using Cygwin64 Compiler and Debugger on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56457209/setting-up-vs-code-for-c-using-cygwin64-compiler-and-debugger-on-windows) ), but it did not work for me.

I cannot comment on the original post, because I do not have enough reputation points, and I cannot answer because I do not know the answer to the original question.

The name of the script is dirigir.c and I can compile. The file dirigir.exe is created. But...

I get the following error:

ERROR: Unable to start debugging. Unexpected GDB output from command "-exec-run". Error creating process /usr/bin/E:\cloud\Backup\Trabalhos com programas\C and Cpp\scripts/e:\cloud\Backup\Trabalhos com programas\C and Cpp\scripts\dirigir.exe, (error 2).

For some reason, **/usr/bin/**... **/** is inserted in the path and the path to the .exe is **duplicated**.

My `launch.json` file is as recommended:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gcc.exe build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "PATH",
                    "value": "%PATH%;z:\\cygwin64\\bin"
                }
            ],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "logging": { "engineLogging": true }, //optional
            "preLaunchTask": "gcc.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

And my `tasks.json` is as follows:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "-Werror", // Optional
                "-Wall", // Optional
                "-Wextra", // Optional
                "-ansi", // Optional
                "-pedantic", // Optional
                "${file}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\cygwin64\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

Do you have any idea how to proceed? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, I got it working.

Based on WardenGnaw's answers in this thread:
[[cppdbg] Cygwin 10.1-1: intergatedTerminal unable to take input #6475](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/6475) and, of course, @stephw's answer in the original question this one is based, I can debug my C program.

First, I saved a VSCODE **workspace in the same folder** where my c programs are.

Then, I used the latest Cygwin gdb version (10.2-1). Did not work (I received the error message that made ask this question). Then, I tried **9.2-1** and now it is working.

[image: Cygwin Setup window and the current gdb version installed.]

It is important to remember to **add "C:\cygwin64\bin" to PATH.**

[image: Environment Varibles windows]

I changed my `launch.json` just a little bit. Notice the **"preLaunchTask"** key does not have the exact same value that the **"label"** key in the `tasks.json` has:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gcc.exe build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "PATH",
                    "value": "%PATH%;C:\\cygwin64\\bin"
                }
            ],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "logging": { "engineLogging": true }, //optional
            "preLaunchTask": "gcc.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

My `tasks.json` is this (notice my name in the end, in the "detail" key):

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "Task generated by Leonardo."
        }
    ]
}
```

I notice something a little bit strange:
When I press F5, it does not work, because the task created is not found.

[image: Dialog saying the task was not found.]

When I edited my `launch.json` file (preLaunchTask key) to the exact same value in the `tasks.json` file, the "not found" error disappears, but the debugging process does not start.

```
"preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file"
```

If I press the Run and debug play button, the debug process does not work either.

[image: Visual Studio Code Run and debug play button.]

When I use the Command Palette (pressing CTRL+SHIFT+P), and click `C/C++: Build and Debug Active File`,

[image: Visual Studio Code Command Palette...]

and then choose the task I created (the second one appears to be automatic),
[image: A list of the tasks available to execute.]

the program is compiled and the debug process is started.

This is my very simple test script:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    /* declare and initialize string */
    char myString[] = "This is an example of string declaration!";

    /* print string */
    printf("%s", myString);

    int numberA = 5;
    int numberB = 10;

    int sum = numberA + numberB;

    /* Printing a number */
    printf("A soma de numberA + numberB é: %d", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

I hope this question and answer can help someone in the future. Peace.

Answer (score 1):

None of the .json changes described here worked for me with gdb 10.2-1. The only thing that did work was the downgrade to gdb 9.2-1, which solved the problem instantly.