# Debugging source file duplicate path

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to run a debugger in VS Code but every time I hit a breakpoint instead source file I am presented with a source file in a path that repeats to times, see blow:
[Source file + path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4gmN.png),
[Source file it tries to open during debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MT1m.png)

As you can see on the second image the path to the source file debugger is trying to open is:

C:\Users\user\Documents\AdvancedC\S2\C\Users\user\Documents\AdvancedC\S2\main.c

and of course, it doesn't exist.

converting the undefined symbol after C to ascii I get that  = "&#61498";

tasks.json:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

lanch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/main.exe",
            "args": [],
            "logging": {
                "moduleLoad": false,
                "trace": true
            },
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:/cygwin64/bin/gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description":  "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }

    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as you, and probably have a similar setup (I also use gcc and gdb from Cygwin). After some research and trial-and-error, I was able to get debugging working by using a different configuration, as explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69684819/17376152

However, I slightly modified my configuration files.

- Use gdb version 9.2-1, as the newer versions don't seem to be working for this environment
- For my tasks.json, I just used the label `"gcc.exe build active file"` instead of `"C/C++: ..."` at the beginning.
- In launch.json, I left the environment variable empty:
  `"environment": [],`

With these changes, my debug process is now working without errors just by pressing F5.

I hope this helps you as well (I see you have the flag `-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel` set, so this might be slightly different).
Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: It is definitely something going on with gdb.exe. I changed to gdb.exe from Mingw and debugging woks very well.  Codeblocks experieneced the same issue and with Mingw gdb.exe it works without any issue.