# VSCode showing command-line error: invalid number: 2 0000 on every C/C++ program, code compiles normally

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code

I'm having some trouble with using VSCode for C/C++ development. Although all my programs compile just fine, the extension pack for C/C++ keeps showing me the following error at the start of every single one of my files:

### command-line error: invalid number: 2 0000

Originally I thought that this may have been a problem with just my laptop, but after downloading VSCode and setting it up for C development in another computer, the same issue arose again.

I've tried disabling the extension pack, which removes the issue, but when I enable it it shows me the same error again. Reinstalling the extension also did not work, even after I deleted all of the files associated with it. Neither did restarting VSCode, restarting my PC or reinstalling VSCode. I also have not found another question here with a satisfying answer.

Below are some images of the issue:[image: in .cpp file][image: in .c files]

Is there a way I can stop this error from appearing, whether it is through fixing the underlying issue or disabling error squiggles for that specific problem? If it's any help, I used the cygnus package to get the gcc and g++ compilers.

Edit: Since people are asking, I'm using windows 10 pro and my gcc and g++ versions are egcs-2.91.57. I downloaded VSCode using the system installer and the only changes I really made to the installation settings from the default ones were adding the options to open folders using VSCode when right clicking. Below is my settings.JSON and the only other relevant settings file I could find(I found it in the extension folder):

settings.JSON:

```
{
"csharp.semanticHighlighting.enabled": false}
```

settings.nls.metadata.json:

```
{
"messages": [
    "Code formatting is using settings from .editorconfig instead of .clang-format. For more information, see the documentation for the 'Default' value of the 'C_Cpp.formatting' setting."
],
"keys": [
    {
        "key": "editorconfig.default.behavior",
        "comment": [
            "Single-quotes are used here, as this message is displayed in a context that does not render markdown. Do not change them to back-ticks."
        ]
    }
],
"filePath": "src\\LanguageServer\\settings"
```

}

Once again, all I did was download the necessary tools using cygnus(specifically cygwin), download VSCode using the system installer, and install the C/C++ extension pack. I have the same issue in 2 systems.

Comment: You have to configure the extensions. You also have to provide relevant information if you want any help. OS, compiler & version, setings.json, etc. People don't magically know how you configured your system.

Comment: Obviously not an error with the code (since all code shows the same error). Rather it's a problem with the way you have configured VSCode. Since you haven't said anything about that it's kind of hard to help.

Comment: It's 'setting it up for C development' that is the problem, Please say what you did there.

Comment: @john All I did was download gcc and g++ using the cygwin package, download VSCode using the system installer and then instal the C/C++ extension. In both systems, this is all I did.

Comment: Try downloading MinGW version of the G++ compiler.  The Cygwin version is not friendly when incorporating with non-Cygwin tools.

Comment: The official  VSCode documentation recommends using msys2 to install MinGW: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) you may want to do all the steps in the VSCode MinGW tutorial and see if that works.

Comment: FYI, I tried copy your code images and pasting into my IDE.  My IDE can't read code images.  Always *paste code as text*.

Comment: @ObamaRules98 VSCode is a lot more complicated than that (too complicated IMHO). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56457209/setting-up-vs-code-for-c-using-cygwin64-compiler-and-debugger-on-windows) for Cygwin instructions

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56457209/setting-up-vs-code-for-c-using-cygwin64-compiler-and-debugger-on-windows

Comment: You mentioned `egcs-2.91.57`. That's a compiler from more that 20 years ago. Please don't use something so old. According to its website, cygwin should have a nice recent GCC version available (GCC 11).

Comment: Uninstall cygwin. You don't need it. Use msys2 to install mingw.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I fixed the issue by unistalling Cygwin and installing the necessary tools using msys2. Leaving the question open in case someone finds a fix that doesn't require reinstalling the compilers.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed MSYS2 through the Chocolatey package manager on Windows, and then installed the latest version of the GCC Mingw-w64 compiler:

```
pacman -S mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc
```

then create a `.vscode` folder in the root of your project folder. Then create the `c_cpp_properties.json` file with the below content:

```json
{
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "mingw64 GCC",
        "compilerPath": "C:\\tools\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
        "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64"
      }
    ],
    "version": 4
  }
```