# Visual Studio Code cannot open source file "iostream"C/C++(1696) on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-code, include-path

I have already checked out [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47616834/visual-studio-code-cannot-open-source-file-iostream) but i could not find anything what would solve the issue for me.

what ever c++ project i start on Visual Studio Code the C++ IntelliSence shows me an error for all the common c++ includes saying: `cannot open source file "iostream"C/C++(1696)`
Same goes for vector, string and so on.

I have tried to follow the instructions on the [Getting Started](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-msvc) for Visual Studio Code
and also tried to uninstall Visual Studio Code also deleting %AppData%/Code folder
But after reinstalling it comes with the same error. Confusingly it still has the extensions
(CMake, C++ Extension Pack and some others ) installed.

Interestingly if i launch code using the developer command prompt the include error C/C++(1696) is gone but if i launch code without that prompt like from a Desktop Shortcut it doesn't.

my c_cpp_properties.json:

```
"configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.34.31933/include"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.22000.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.34.31933/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x64",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
```

Comment: Did you setup VS Code properly? Like compilers, other tools?

Comment: i think so, as for example cmake does build successfully. Also as mentioned when i launch code using developer powershell 2019 it does not show this error.

Comment: BTW why use VS Code when you have Visual studio installed?

Comment: Intellisense needs to be configured separately from the "real" compiler. Total flexibility in VS Code!